# Angular ng-repeat. Doing a nested repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to angular! So two sets of data. One containing meals, one containing entries. Each meal can have several entries, but each entry only relates to one meal.

In my data, the meals table has an Id, and in the entries table, there is a reference to the meal id with a meal_id property.

meal:

```
{
id: 4,
user_id: 3,
date: 12345678,
name: "soFood",
location: "Litchfield, CT",
rating: 1,
notes: "This is a note here",
image: "http://www.image.com"
},
```

entry:

```
{
id: 3,
meal_id: 4,
name: "Fet UP",
rating: 0,
notes: null,
image: "http://not.anote.here"
}
```

At the moment I am able to repeat the meals. I'd like to be able to uniquely repeat the entries for an individual meal.

So for a list of meals, be able to click on one and have a list of its unique entries show up.

I know I have to somehow get the meal_id to compare to the id of the meals but I'm unsure how to use ng-repeat doing that?

Comment: can you provide a snipit of your view and controller code

Comment: Can you combine them at server? Simplest would be each meal had child array of entries. Will need to map them to structure like that anyway in javascript if don't do it at server. Show us how you get this data

Answer (score 0):

You will first affect the current meal to a variable in your upper ng-repeat, i.e. `ng-repeat="meal in meals"`. This current meal is known in the scope of the ng-repeat directive. You can use it to filter an entries array and use the result in an inner ng-repeat :

```
<li ng-repeat="meal in meals">
    <div ng-repeat="entry in (entries | filter : {'meal_id': meal.id})">
    </div>
</li>
```